# Can I know commit list of specific branch?

Tags: git, git-flow

I want to know commit list of specific branch.

```
ex)
* f322894 - (HEAD, develop) blahblah1 (2 seconds ago) <author>
* 54c828e - blahblah2 (2 hours ago) <author>
* 3eaeafe - blahblah13 (16 hours ago) <author>
* 2b16c8d - blahblah14 (17 hours ago) <author>
*   9c4482b - Merge branch 'feature/ftTest' into develop (22 hours ago) <author>
|\
| * abb35c3 - feature commit (24 hours ago) <author>
* | cab5dae - dot commit (24 hours ago) <author>
|/
* e365eab - e2222 (24 hours ago) <author>
* 0c3c340 - testCoMIT (24 hours ago) <author>
* bb2d382 - (master) Initial commit (25 hours ago) <author>
```

hash number 9c4482b and abb35c3 are commit of feature/ftTest branch. 
Other commits are commit of develop.
What do I type git command?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the commit history of a specific branch, you should do:

> git log [branch name]

This will give you the commit history for that branch. However, it is important to remember that branches in Git are like pointers to commits. So it is not necessary that a commit in a branch's history was commit while using that branch. For example, I can create a new branch at 9c4482b and that will still show up in the branch's history.

Comment: thanks. :) But Your answer is not that I expected. Bacuase My english writting skill is so terrible, So I can not explain problem well.